# How to paint all VCL Styles tab sheet controls to a given canvas when the tab is not visible to the user?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, vcl-styles

Using C++ Builder 10.2, VCL & VCL Styles...

I have a `TPageControl` that has `TFrames` on each of its `TTabsheets`. One of these frames contains some `TEdit` controls that show data read from a device. After the reading is acquired and the frame is updated, the system may create a screenshot of this frame and store it in a jpeg file.

Since the `TTabsheet` in the `TPageControl` with the `TEdit` controls may not be visible when the jpeg is created, the jpeg may not have the text contents of the `TEdit` controls painted. This has given me fits.

I have found that by using a `TStaticText` that is styled, the text appears in the jpeg. This seems to be due to the fact that `TStaticTextStyleHook.Paint` (in `VCL.StdCtrls.pas`) draws the control itself rather than letting Windows do it.

There are two problems with using `TStaticText`. Selecting the `SystemStyle` choice (Windows) causes `TStaticTextStyleHook.Paint` to skip painting the control itself and delegates to Windows (I think). Also, the appearance of `TStaticText` isn't exactly what I want, but I may have to live with it.

Is Windows refusing to paint `TEdit` control contents because the parent is not `Visible`?

Is there a way to force Windows to paint the `TEdit` controls in this situation?

`UpdateWindow()` and `RedrawWindow()` does not work.

Comment: Windows does not update controls that are not visible, as it's a waste of CPU cycles to do so. (Why waste time drawing something that can't be seen and therefore has no reason to be drawn?)

Comment: As @Ken says. Hence MS came up with the `WM_PRINT` message. It's an explicit request to a window to paint its content to a given canvas even when it's not currently visible.

Comment: @Victoria: But it only works if the window handles the message, which not all controls do. I've not looked to see if TEdit does.

Comment: @Ken, a friend of mine gave me an access to Delphi 7 source code (have no Delphi by hand) and it seems that `PaintTo` method should do what is needed here (cannot say how much it's been modified since that time or how style hooks act in favor of that method).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have tried PaintTo(), but it does not paint the contents of TEdit controls on my panel:
PnlJpeg->PaintTo(bmp->Canvas, 0, 0);
I also tried WM_PRINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT but none of the panel is painted. Still investigating.

Comment: `PaintTo` if not changed since Delphi 7 passes `WM_PAINT` message directly to the window proc (but handling of that message may later eliminate painting because the parent is not visible to the user, but that's what I cannot confirm). `WM_PRINT` is what should be used here, but I'm afraid that VCL doesn't handle it correctly.